# URLConnection.getInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException when trying to connect between an application and a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to develop an application which has communication between a servlet file running on Tomcat.

Below is the code in my application, which is trying to connection to this servlet, send request and get response.

```
 private URLConnection getServletConnection() {
    try {
        URL servletURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/test/servlet");
        URLConnection conn = servletURL.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        return conn;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And below is the code where exception is thrown:

```
URLConnection conn = getServletConnection();
OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
ServletRequestMessage srm = new ServletRequestMessage(2, username, password);
oos.writeObject(srm);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
```

The exception is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/test/servlet
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify where exactly is the `FileNotFoundException` thrown?

Comment: In addition to @Andrew did you verify `http://localhost:8080/test/servlet` that url works properly?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov 'InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream()' throws the exception. And the interesting thing is the code 'OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream()' before doesn't

Comment: @Fess Yes, that works in the browser.

Comment: @Cacheing: Change `conn.setDoOutput(true);` to `conn.setDoOutput(false);` and see. I think this line is changing the request method.

Comment: @ShashankKadne no, it doesn't work. And after I changed it, I got this exception: `java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)`

Comment: Why you don't use `HttpURLConnection`?  Try to replace `URLConnection ` with  `HttpURLConnection` and add flags: `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);`  `connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);`   Anyways for Servlets I used `DefaultHttpClient` with `Credentials`. If you need example how I implemented it, I can paste.

Comment: @Fess Can it be the problem with my configuration at the Tomcat side? By now, I just put the complied classes files under classes folder and changed the web.xml file. Do I need to put the .java files under Tomcat? If so, where should I put these .java files?

Comment: @Fess Can you give me the example? That would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Method `getInputStream()` is huge (see [here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.html)). FileNotFoundException is thrown either when response code is 404 or 410. You should probably look at your Tomcat configuration.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov um.. pretty huge. I changed the Tomcat server.xml under conf folder and added `<Context path="/test" docBase="test" reloadable="true"/>` because the servlet is under a new folder "test". In webapps/test/WEB-INF/web.xml, I added <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> for the servlet class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Side**

```
public class ServletImpl extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

    ....
    public ServletImpl() {
      super();      
    }

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
    super.init(config);         


    /*
     Application scope 
     Shared between all servlets, JSP pages, and custom tags within a J2EE application 
     or within the whole container if no applications are defined.
     The programmatic interface to the application scope is the 'ServletContext' object.         
     */


    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("base", config.getInitParameter("base"));
      /* where "base" is iniy param in web.xml
         <init-param>
    <param-name>base</param-name>
    <param-value>/ServlrtName/sys</param-value>
    </init-param>       


       */



....



}
    ....
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doPost(request, response);
}


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
    Enumeration<?> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();


    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {

        String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();

        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);


         if("sub".equals(paramName)){

            paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

            if(paramValues.length > 0){

                String param = paramValues[0];
                // do something
                ....
            }               

        }           
    }
}


....
// prepear response 
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println(mMessageResponseStr);
    out.close();
```

Here I used `sub` tag, see: `if("sub".equals(paramName)){`.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>ServlrtName</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>ServlrtName</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ServlrtName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.demo.servlet.ServletImpl</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>base</param-name>
    <param-value>/ServlrtName/sys</param-value>
    </init-param>
  <init-param>

        ....

</servlet>

...

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServlrtName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sys/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Client Side**

I used `DefaultHttpClient` and `HttpPost`. I send `sub` tag . Here  is a method that sends data to Servlet:

```
 public boolean send(String data) {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
    boolean success = false;

    try {           
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String url = "your URL";


        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub", data));


        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != 200){
                mResErr.onErrorResponse(statusCode);                    
            }

            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // get data from line


            }
            is.close();


        } else {
            //response is null/
        }
        success = true;

        mRes.onHttpResponse(mArr);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        mResErr.onErrorResponse(e);
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    if (httpclient != null) {
        // resource cleanup
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return success;
}
```

** Comment, before you start check connectivity, remove user/password from server side. If all works as expected switch it back and use on client side:

```
Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pswd");


         httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                    cred);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I have a question for your web.xml: where is your ServletImpl.class file is? Is it under webapps/com/demo/servlet?

Comment: Yes, ` <servlet-class>com.demo.servlet.ServletImpl</servlet-class>`. From client for my example URL: **http://127.0.0.1:8080/ServlrtName/sys**

Comment: So do you need to change the server.xml file?

Comment: not at all, you use only web.xml in your Servlet project under `../WebContent/WEB-INF/`

Comment: Like this link says: http://cs.calstatela.edu/~abbott/Courses/CS_320b/Running%20a%20Servlet%20under%20Tomcat.html

Comment: where is your servlet project? is it under webapps?

Comment: No, i run it from Eclipse EE. But sure you can run it from default folder under `webapps`. As I know you must `register` to server.xml your servlet:  put this row under `Engine` tag:   <Context docBase="ServlrtName" path="/ServlrtName" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ServlrtName"/></Host> But this is example that I use for Eclipse. You can google additional inforamtion about adding Context to server.xml

Comment: Wow! I can set up the connection between my application and servlet using your way now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, is your Credentials part like an authentication process? If so, can you elaborate on that? How do I implement it on the client side, and how do I implement it on the server side? Thanks a lot.